# KendoUI Datasource when not bound to any controls

Tags: javascript, api, kendo-ui, datasource

I'm using a KendoUI Datasource in several places, some are bound to controls others are not.  The call is to a remote web service and can be quite expensive some I'm trying to just execute it first.

The first time I need the data is for a situation where it is not bound to a control.

```
I call a function similar to this to create the datasouce:

function BuildDS() {
    var DS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "../WS/GetData",
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "POST"
            }
        }
    });

    return DS;
}
```

I then have another function which iterates through the DS.

```
function GetName(DSIn, fieldID) {

    DSIn.read();

    var visname = "";
    $.each(DSIn.data(), function (idx, vis) {
        if (vis.FIELD_ID == fieldID) {
            visname = vis.DISPLAY_LABEL;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return visname;
}
```

I can see that the remote web service is being invoked and returns the data as expected. However the data() property of the DS always returns no data.

When I bind the same datasource to a Kendo control then the data is populated on the DS.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving the data from the server is an async operation, so when you iterate, this call hasn't completed yet. You should use [`fetch`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#methods-fetch) instead:

```
dataSource.fetch(function(){
  var data = this.data();
  console.log(data.length); 

  // now you can iterate over data
});
```

Comment: No luck, I'm afraid.  The fetch function doesn't get invoked until the DS is bound to something.

Comment: that's strange - which version are you using? check this demo: http://jsbin.com/AnoXini/4/edit (fetch, shows 77 records) and compare with this http://jsbin.com/AnoXini/3/edit (read, shows 0 records)

Comment: I'm using the latest build (2013.3.1316). The only difference with the samples I've seen is that I'm doing a HTTP post while the examples are usually GETs.

Comment: I'm calling the above functions in $(document).ready, I suspect my issue is that I can't call them until the DOM is loaded.

Comment: well, you don't have to wait for the ready event to create/populate the DS; I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, ultimately - in any case, as you can see in the demo, if you want to get the data and iterate over it, you can use fetch

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I ended up just doing a Ajax call and setting the data property of the DataSource with the results.

Comment: @keitn I suggest either accepting my answer or posting and accepting your own answer, so this question doesn't show up as unsolved anymore